# Como faço uma data annotation, poder acessar valor de outra propriedade?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho minhas seguintes propriedades:

```
public ETipoPessoa TipoPessoa {get;set;}
public string CnpjCPF {get;set;}

public enum ETipoPessoa {
     Fisica,
     Juridica
}
```

Eu tenho essa condição, se TipoPessoa = Fisica, eu preciso passar uma annotation que valide o CPF, caso contrário TipoPessoa = Juridica valide o CNPJ

Sendo assim, como faço uma data annotation, poder acessar valor de outra propriedade ?

Ou seja, minha annotation tem que pegar o valor que veio do TipoPessoa, para validar o que é o que...

Comment: O CPF sempre tem 11 dígitos. O CNPJ sempre tem 14. O `TipoPessoa` não é necessário.

Comment: É necessário na View para a máscara

Comment: Você pode colocar o campo sem necessariamente mapeá-lo no banco de dados, já que a máscara é importante.

Comment: Cigano, ao meu ver é bem importante ter mapeado, ainda mais quando formos filtrar por "TipoPessoa"

Answer (score 3):

Ainda não é o que você quer, mas existe uma foma de fazer uma validações a nível do Modelo.

```
public class Pessoa : IValidatableObject
{
    public ETipoPessoa TipoPessoa {get;set;}
    public string CnpjCPF {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validations = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (TipoPessoa == ETipoPessoa.Fisica)
        {
            bool cpfValido;
            ... // validação de CPF
            if (!cpfValido)
                validations.Add(new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido"));
        }

        if (TipoPessoa == ETipoPessoa.Juridica)
        {
            bool cnpjValido;
            ... // validação de CNPJ 
            if (!cnpjValido)
                validations.Add(new ValidationResult("CNPJ Inválido"));
        }
        return validations;
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que seria legal você colocar dentro de cada `if` como disparar uma mensagem de erro para o `Controller`.